# R: Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data: x

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
mydata <- data.frame(variable = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                     value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
p <- ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = 1:3, y = value, group = variable, color = variable)) + geom_line()
> p
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6): x
```

Running the above code gives me the error: `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6): x`. I think it has to do with how I set `x = 3` under `aes`. What I want to plot to look like is something like this:

[image]

Comment: Isn't the error clear? Try: `x = 1:6`.

Comment: I want the x axis to range from 1:3.

Comment: `x =rep(1:3, 2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You chart image has x-axis labeled as "Iteration", but that information is not included in your example in "mydata". It would be hard to help you without this missing information.

Based on your comments, it appears that you may be interested in setting the **limits** of the x-axis. In that case, you could try using something like this.

```
p2 <- ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + 
  geom_line() +
  xlim(1,3)
p2
```

Comment: Also, setting x = 1:3 inside the aes() simply creates the vector x = c(1,2,3) to be used inside the ggplot. This does not subset the data or set limits on the x-axis.